# The constructor of VrVideoView from Google Virtual reality

Tags: android, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality, vrvideoview

When I call the constructor of `VrVideoView`, like:

```
VrVideoView view=new VrVideoView(this)
```

i catch this exception:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.common.VrWidgetRenderer com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.common.VrWidgetView.createRenderer(android.content.Context, com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.common.VrWidgetRenderer$GLThreadScheduler, float, float)"

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Yes i do ! The problem is just because the emulator don't emulate Vrvideo view but it run well on real device !